# Why can I call this static method using the class name but not using a class instance?

Tags: c#, class, static-methods, method-call, member-access

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Main(args);//instance reference error,use type name instead

        var p = new Program();
        Program.Main(args);//error disappears
    }
}
```

I think I understand that statics are not associated with object instances, but what I'm having trouble with is aren't classes synonymous with objects?  Or aren't classes used in creating objects?  So why does the error disappear when I use the class name if classes are essentially objects?

I get that I haven't yet created an instance of `Main` and won't be.  Is that the only thing that makes the difference?  Maybe it's just not being explained properly in this class I'm taking.

Comment: "aren't classes synonomous with objects" - no, in the same way that "The blueprint for a house" isn't the same as "my house". C# stops you from calling a static method on an *instance* of a type to prevent it from *looking* like it's going to be something instance-specific when it's not.

Comment: `if classes are essentially objects?` no.... classes are not objects. They are templates for creating objects... Classes are types and you can create variables of types and they are called instances. Static methods are created for types and they can be called only by using type. That's why the error disappear..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your confusion is a very natural one, and it is exacerbated by the design of C# in this respect. I'll try to explain as we go, and I'll reformulate your questions to be easier to answer:

> Is `class` synonymous with `object`?

No. Let's be very, very clear on this point. **"Object"** has a specific meaning in C#.  An object is always an *instance of a type*. There are two broad kinds of object in C#: *reference types* which are *copied by reference*, like `string` and value types which are *copied by value*, like `int`.

Later you will learn about *boxing*, which is the mechanism by which an instance of value type may be used in a context that expects a reference, but don't worry about that for now.

In C# a *class* defines a *reference type*. *Instances* of that class are objects. The class itself is not an object.

The justification for this comes from the real world. The class "all objects which are newspapers" is not itself a newspaper. The class "all people who speak French" is not itself a French speaker. It is a category error to confuse *a description of a set of things* with *a specific example* of the thing!

(You may wish to examine closely the design of *prototype inheritance* languages such as JavaScript. In JS we make a specific object that is the *prototypical example* of a kind of thing, and we make a constructor object that represents the *factory* for new examples of that kind of thing; the prototype and the constructor work together to make new instances, and both are genuinely objects. But again, your question is about C#, so let's stick to that for now.)

> are classes used in creating objects?

Yes. We *instantiate* a class with `new`; since all classes are reference types, `new` produces a reference to a novel object.

> So why does the error disappear when i use the class name, if classes are essentially objects?

Classes are not objects, but I understand your confusion. It certainly looks like the class name is being used in a context where you would expect an object. (You might be interested to examine closely the design of languages like Python where classes *are* objects, but your question is about C# so let's stick to that.)

To resolve this confusion you need to understand that the *member access operator*, also called the "dot operator", in C# is one of the most flexible and sophisticated operators. This makes it easy to use but hard to understand!

The key thing to understand is that the member access operator always has this form:

- On the left of the dot is an expression that *evaluates to a thing that has members*
- On the right of the dot is a *simple name*.
- Though it is possible, and common, for `thing` to be an object and `thing.name` to be an object, it is also possible for either or both to *not* be an object.

When you say `p.Main` the compiler says "I know that `p` is an instance of `Program`, and I know that `Main` is a name. Does that make sense?"

The first thing the compiler does is verifies that `Program` -- `p`'s type -- has an accessible member `Main`, which it does. At this point *overload resolution* takes over, and we discover that the only possible meaning of `Main` is a static method. **This is likely a mistake** because `p` is an instance, and we're attempting to invoke a static through the instance. C#'s designers could have allowed this -- it is allowed in other languages. But since this is a likely mistake, they disallowed it.

When you type `Program.Main`, *`Program` is not an object*. The compiler verifies that `Program` refers to a type and *types have members*. Once again, overload resolution takes over and it determines that the only possible meaning is that `Main` is being invoked. Since `Main` is static and the receiver -- the thing on the left of the dot -- refers to a type, this is allowed.

> Maybe it's just not being explained properly in this class I'm taking.

I edit technical books and other course materials and a great many of them explain these concepts very poorly. Also a great many instructors have vague and confused notions about the relationships between classes, objects, variables, and so on. I encourage you to question your instructor closely on these matters until you are satisfied with their explanations.

That said, once you have a solid grasp on these matters then you can start to take shortcuts. As expert C# programmers we say "`p` is an object which..." because we *all* know that we mean "`p` is a variable, the value of which is a reference to an object which..."

I think it is helpful for the beginner to spell it out, but you will very quickly become more relaxed about it.

One other thing that you did not ask but is important:

> What about reflection?

.NET has a *reflection* system which allows you to take things that are *not* objects, like classes, structs, interfaces, methods, properties, events, and so on, and obtain an object which describes them. (The analogy being that a mirror image is not *reality* but it sure looks like it enough to understand reality.)

It is important to remember that the reflection object is *not the class*. It is an object which *describes* the class. If you use reflection in your program like this:

```
Type t = typeof(Program);
```

then the value of `t` is a reference to the `Type` object that describes the characteristics of class `Program`. You could inspect that object and determine that there was a `MethodInfo` for method `Main`, and so on. But the object *is not the class*.  You cannot say

```
t.Main();
```

for example. There are ways to invoke methods via reflection, but it is a mistake to think of the `Type` object as *being* the class. It *reflects* the class.

Another question you did not ask but is germane to your education:

> What you're saying here is that *values* are instances of objects, but certain programming language constructs such as classes are not objects that can be manipulated like values. Why is it that some programming language constructs in C# are "first class" -- they can be treated as data manipulated by the program -- and some are "second class", and cannot be so manipulated?

That question gets to the crux of language design itself. All language design is a process of examining past languages, observing their strengths and weaknesses, coming up with principles that attempt to build on strengths while mitigating weaknesses, and then resolving the countless contradictions entailed when principles come into conflict with each other.

We all want a camera that is lightweight, inexpensive, and takes great pictures, but as the saying goes, you can only have two. The designers of C# were in a similar position:

- We want languages to have a small number of concepts that must be understood by the novice. Moreover, we achieve this by *unifying* disparate concepts into hierarchies; structs, classes, interfaces, delegates and enums are all *types*.  if, while, foreach are all *statements*. And so on.
- We want to be able to build programs that manipulate values that are important to the developer in powerful ways. Making functions "first class" for example opens up powerful new ways to program.
- We want programs to have little enough redundancy that developers do not feel like they are forced into unnecessary ceremony, but sufficient redundancy that humans can understand the program as written.

And now the big ones:

- We want the language to be general enough to allow line-of-business developers to write programs that represent any concept in their business domain
- We want the language to be understandable by machines to the extent that the machines can find likely problems before the program even runs. That is, the language must be *statically analyzable*.

But like the camera, you can't have all of these at once. C# is a general-purpose programming language designed for programming in the large with a strong static type checker for finding real-world mistakes before they make it into production. It is precisely *because* we want to find the sort of error you're encountering that we do *not* allow types to be treated as first-class values. If you treat types as first class then huge amounts of static analysis capability goes out the window!

Other language designers made completely different choices; the consequences of Python saying "classes are a kind of function, and functions are a kind of object" dramatically moves the language towards our desired goal of hierarchical simplicity and first-class treatment of language concepts, and dramatically away from ability to statically determine correctness. That's the right choice for Python, but not for C#.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to write that answer!  very helpful! Can you recommend any resources that break it down in a similar fashion? I hate to seek this kind of advice on here but, i trust the people in here, moreso than amazon reviews. so forgive me if i'm exceeding the realm or rules of the platform.

Comment: I would add as a C# design problem; we want the execution of the program to be efficient. Because this often causes conflict with how language features are exposed to programmers.

Answer (score -1):

Static methods in classes are meant to be connected to the class. Other methods are meant to be connected to objects. This way, you can access static methods without having to create an object. In c++, this the boilerplate code you would use:

```
className::staticMethod();
```